# When is a function mapping from a space of measures to the real numbers continuous

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, continuity

Let $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ be any set and let $\mathcal{M}(S)$ be the space of measures on $(S,\mathcal{B}(S))$ (Maybe I need to be more specific about what kind of measures here?) and equip it for example with the weak topology. Define a map
$$T:\mathcal{M}(S) \to \mathbb{R}, \quad\mu \mapsto T(\mu).$$
Is there any intuition on when such a map $T$ is continuous? Is for example $T(\mu):=\mu(S)$ continuous? How would a non continuous map look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us simplify things a bit. Let $\mathcal{M}(S)$ denote finite signed Borel measures, equipped with the coarsest topology obtained by requiring that testing against bounded and continuous functions $\varphi \in C_b(S)$ is a continuous operation. This is what people usually refer to as the weak topology.

Thus, by definition, maps of the form $\mu \mapsto\langle\varphi,\mu\rangle$ for $\varphi \in C_b(S)$ are continuous.  On the other hand, something discontinuous is also pretty straightforward to construct. Consider a family $\mu_n$ of probability measures that are all Gaussian with mean $0$ and variance $1/n$. It is easy to check that the sequence $\mu_n$ converges weakly to a Dirac measure at $0$, $\delta_0$. But, $\mu_n([0,\infty))=1/2$ does not converge to $\delta_0([0,\infty))=1$. Thus, the map $\mu \mapsto \mu([0,\infty))$ cannot be continuous with respect to the weak topology.